# Replace everything between 2 characters exclusive

Tags: regex, rust

I want to replace the `6379` in the string `"172.20.0.3:6379@16379"` with another port number.

I've tried this but it says the escape sequence "\K" is not valid.

```rust
use regex::Regex;
let ip = "172.20.0.3:6379@16379"
let re = Regex::new(r":\K[^@]+").unwrap();
let new_ip = re.replace(ip, "1234");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:[^:@]+@` to match everything between `:` and `@` inclusively, and add the two characters back in the replacement.

```
let re = Regex::new(r":[^:@]+@").unwrap();
let new_ip = re.replace(ip, ":1234@");
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1ac2f851b12008cb8fa65dbed07085e0)